# Datatable require success function at the time of server side pagination call in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

We require success method in bellow javascript/jquery Datatable function. It is possible?, Because i want show alert Msg after successfully get Data from server side pagination.

```
table = $('#TempTable').DataTable({

destroy: true,
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"lengthMenu": [[5, 10], [5, 10]],
"ajax":{
    url :"userBack.php",
    data: {  getTemp : Temp},
    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
    error: function(){  
        $(".Table-error").html("");
        $("#Table").append('<tbody class="Table-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
        $("#Table").css("display","none");
        switchLoader(false);
    }
},
"columns": [
    {"data": "id"},
    {"data": "name"}

]
```

} );

Comment: I've not done this but you should be able to use [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) as a function or [ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) as a function.  The concept comes from this info - "success - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server use ajax.dataSrc (above), or use ajax as a function (below)." (in the ajax reference on datatables docs)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datatables is coded to use the success callback in ajax and it breaks if you intercept it. [Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/109910/#Comment_109910)

You can also make use of [jQuery ajax **dataFilter** callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$('table[id=entries]').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/entries',
        dataFilter: function(response) {
            var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (json_response.recordsTotal) {
                alert("There're entries");
            }else{
                alert("There're no entries");
            }
            return response;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.error(xhr.responseJSON);
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** Return a *String*, not JSON in dataFilter callback.